# Rails Model Setup Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I'm working on a rails 4 app and i have two models Developers and Apps. A developer can have many apps and belongs to many apps. (Multiple developers for an app) I have successfully setup a joining table and everything works but i want to extent this so that a developer is either a :founder where he can have access to edit the app or a collaborator who only has access to view the app. Any suggestions on the best possible was to achieve this functionality?

App

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, class_name: 'Developer', association_foreign_key: :collaborator_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, class_name: 'Developer', association_foreign_key: :founder_id
```

Developer

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps, foreign_key: 'collaborator_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps, foreign_key: 'founder_id'
```

Comment: how did you define relationship on `App` and `Developer` through `has_many through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Comment: You have 2 choices

 1. Create a new table similar to what @zolter answer suggested and use `has_many through` instead of `hbtm` have some check in `edit` and `update` methods in your controller.
 2. modify your `hbtm` to become a proper model table: add migration to create timestamps columns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542976/add-timestamps-to-an-existing-table and add `role` column to the table as well. Then create the `model` file in your `models`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create another table:

```
  def change
    create_table :access_restricts do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :application_id
      t.integer :role_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

User and application will have many assess_restricts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use single table inheritance in this case.

[STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance)

[STI SAMPLE](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations)