# How to show online users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a simple chat, and I need to list out users online. I don't use `devise` for authentication, there's a custom `user` model which authenticates via `omniauth`.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages, dependent: :delete_all
    class << self
        def from_omniauth(auth)
            provider = auth.provider
            uid = auth.uid
            info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
            user.name = info.name
            user.avatar_url = info.image
            user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
            user.save!
            user
        end
    end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: cookies[:user_id]) if cookies[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

I tried to do that in such way: add to `application_controller.rb` a `show_online` method:

```
def show_online
    @users = User.where(status: online)
end

helper_method :online_users
```

and then add to a view:

```
<%= online_users.each do |user| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

but it throws an exception `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'online_users' for #<MessagesController:0x007f52d7f82740>)`

[source code](https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/chatclone.git) here

**EDIT**

the best solution as for me I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805479/rails-how-to-check-for-online-users), but I completely don't get how to implement it correctly :( But that's definitely what I need

Comment: probably `Users.find(:all, :conditions => ["status = ?", "online"])` returns nil thats why.

Comment: Don't quote me on that but I'm pretty sure that this find syntax you are using got removed a long time ago. Also provide a proper error message. It should tell you _what object_ has no each method which would help debugging a lot.

Comment: @2called-chaos it returns `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 This is because the find method takes an ID to find one single record (and I guess you don't have an ID `:all`). Please lookup the documentation here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: do you check my post do you use the possibilities I have mentioned @AlexNikolaev94

Comment: Post your `Helper` file too.

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Is the controller that's contains the action used to render the view (the one that calls online_users) inheriting from ApplicationController?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 I have edited my answer and it should now solve your problem.

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<% %>` not `<%= %>`

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <ul>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
</ul>
<% end%>
```

Secondly

but also you need to check whether `@users` is nil so nil.each each will throw that error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass)`

so it will be look like

```
<% if @users %>
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
  </ul>
 <% end%>
<% end %>
```

or in controller

```
def show_online
  @users = User.where(status: 'Online')
end
```

and

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= user.try(:name) %></li>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

why I choose [where not find all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232971/rails-find-all-by-vs-where)

Comment: That would stop the array from being printed but has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: you dnt need if statement, if using User.where. it will return empty array `[]` if nobody online.

Comment: @RajarshiDas got it, for `user.name`.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

**The error you get can be solved in one of two ways.**
You can use helper methods and call them from your view, as it seems you want to do.
Or, you can avoid using them completely and just call the show_online method from whichever method is currently being when the view is loaded. If you're going to the `show`, it'll be the show method, and so on and so on.

Your own answer does correctly fix the errors using the first method, but I recommend this way.

What needs to be done to implement these fixes:

- Call show_online when the `new` is being loaded so that view can access the @users variable. We can do that with **before_action**
- In the view, you have a loop which iterates over `online_users`, but it should iterate over `@users`
- In the that same loop in the view, you have a simple syntax error. The first line starts with `<%=` but should start with `<%` without the **=**. This should be changed no matter what way you write the code.

#### So all together the code is:

**application_controller.rb**

```
#put this line at the top of the controller, just below the line ApplicationController:: .....
before_action :show_online, only: [:new]

def show_online
    @users = User.where(online: true)
```

**the view file**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <ul>
      <li><%= user.name %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

### Why this method?

- Making one method to get the online users means the logic is only one one place
- Having your logic/code in one place means you don't ever repeat yourself, and you know where to look if a problem occurs
- Using before_action means the call won't be made unless it is needed
- If you later add pages which need to get the list of online users, you just add those to the list of methods in the brackets here: `only: [:new]`
- When choosing between placing logic in a view or in a controller, the correct answer is almost always the controller

Comment: thank you! but I actually don't get properly `show` method - the `current_user` method must be nested into it?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 You can call the **show_online** method from whichever method is loading the view, it doesn't have to be the show method. What is the name of your view file? That will tell us what method we need.

Comment: I've just done as you've said - `<% @users.each %>` and now it returns me `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass)`. while when I've done that as I've said in my answer, there were no errors, but the online users were just not shown in the list.

Comment: What is the name of the view file?

Comment: now there's a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'show_online' for #<MessagesController:0x007f21e4279a18>)`

Comment: I see. Make sure `show_online` is not private. If it is not private and you get the same error, change the word **before_action** to **before_filter**. But only if you still get the error after you make show_online not private.

Comment: The only reason you might need to change it to **before_filter** is because that was the name of **before_action** until it was recently changed in a new rails version.

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Can you post a link to the entire controller code as well as the entire view file?

Comment: I found an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805479/rails-how-to-check-for-online-users) that does correctly what I need, but I don't completely get HOW to implement it :( If you could help, please e-mail @ alexandernikolaev94@gmail.com me or write me in [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011665566894)

Comment: I will email you if you continue to have trouble, but for right now just try to do this: add that code from the answer you found to your user model. Make a migration to add a time stamp attribute to the user table called `last_online`. Every time the a page is loaded or a user does any action, set the user's `last_online` attribute to Time.now

Comment: Once you do that, you'll be able to just change your logic in your application controller to get the online users. From before when you did `User.where(online: true)`, you'll change that to `User.where(online_now: true)`

Comment: should the migration look like `add_last_online_to_users last_online:timestamp`?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 No, see why [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542976/add-timestamps-to-an-existing-table)

Comment: so I need to create the migration file manually and then migrate my database, right?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 Yeah. You can name the migration whatever then go find it in db/migrate/ and edit it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108204/discussion-between-alexnikolaev94-and-matthew-cliatt).

Answer (score 0):

Your application controller code is wrong:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def show_online
    @users = User.where(status: 'online')
  end
  helper_method :online_users
end
```

Should be:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def online_users
    @users ||= User.where(status: 'online')
  end
  helper_method :online_users
end
```

Comment: Correct, but it's the one he asked about. The other issues are not related to the exception.

Answer (score -1):

From the error message it seems like your **@users** is not an array or **ActiveRecord::Relation**.

I would print out the @users on the view to debug. Also, `find(:all, :conditions => ["status = ?", "online"])` is not the preferable way to query.

Use `User.where(:status => "online")`. Reference - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: still it doesn't help :(

Comment: What's the outcome of your debug then? The same error? And the class if `@users`?

Comment: Thanks. A couple of errors: 1. I think you mean `@online_users` not `online_users`. 2. change `@users = User.where(status: online)` to `@online_users = User.where(status: "online")`. Also, I suggest you to add `<%= @online_users.class %>` on the view to see what class is it.