# Add timestamps to existing table in db Ruby on Rails using rails g migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Is there a

```
rails g migration AddTimestampsToModel something:something
```

that will generate

```rb
class AddTimestampsToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_timestamps :model, null: false, default: -> { 'NOW()' }
  end
end
```

This code comes up in this topic but I don't have enough rating to comment on the response of one of the user.

[Add timestamps to existing table in db Rails 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520907/add-timestamps-to-existing-table-in-db-rails-5)

[Answer in above link post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476642/19431104)

`rails g migration AddTestToTest timestamps:timestamp null:false default: NOW()`

asks for function and I am not sure what this means

Comment: When creating a new model in Rails the timestamps are added by default. They are names `created_at` and `updated_at`. So I am wondering: do you want to add these default timestamps to a model that is lacking them, or do you want to create a custom timestamp like `accepted_at` or such ?

Comment: I am looking to add them to a model that was originally created without the created_at and updated_at columns.

Comment: Have you tried the favorited answer from the thread you mentionned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520907/add-timestamps-to-existing-table-in-db-rails-5 cause it seems non trivial and some coders seems to have more luck while trying different migrations syntaxes

Comment: I have looked at the favourited answer. My question is more about having the `rails g migration` command automatically generate the right migration internals. I can generate a blank migration and manually enter in
```
class AddTimestampsToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_timestamps :model, null: false, default: -> { 'NOW()' }
  end
end
```
and the migration will work correctly. 
Just seeing if there is a shortcut per say.